# TypeScript, checking for keys and subkeys and its variants

Tags: typescript

How to reduce code size?

```
  getAlreadySaved(goal: GoalModel): number {

        if (goal.status && goal.status.investedAmount && !goal.status.pendingIncoming && !goal.status.pendingOutgoing) {
            return goal.status.investedAmount;

        } else if (goal.status && goal.status.investedAmount && goal.status.pendingIncoming && !goal.status.pendingOutgoing) {
            return goal.status.investedAmount + goal.status.pendingIncoming;

        } else if (goal.status && goal.status.investedAmount && !goal.status.pendingIncoming && goal.status.pendingOutgoing) {
            return goal.status.investedAmount - goal.status.pendingOutgoing;

        } else if (goal.status && goal.status.investedAmount && goal.status.pendingIncoming && goal.status.pendingOutgoing) {
            return goal.status.investedAmount + goal.status.pendingIncoming - goal.status.pendingOutgoing;

        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Find invalid cases first then return early. In this case, it looks like the initial `goal.status` check is primarily for presence check. You can remove that from the entire logic and put it up front, returning `0` early.

Now the whole point of TypeScript is to provide types to your data so you won't be doing unnecessary type checks in code. In the case of `pendingIncoming`, `pendingOutgoing` and `investedAmount`, they're numbers. The type for `status` should at least define them as `number`. Without a value, they should at least be initialized to 0. That should remove the unnecessary conditions.

With that, your code is essentially just:

```
getAlreadySaved(goal: GoalModel): number {
  const status:Status = goal.status;

  if(!status) return 0;

  // If we can assume they're numbers, we can safely say we can do math.
  return status.investedAmount + status.pendingIncoming - status.pendingOutgoing;
}
```

Comment: Even if `investedAmount`, `pendingIncoming`, and `pendingOutgoing` are declared as numbers, they can easily get null/undefined in run time. I got burnt many many times by the objects received from API calls. What I am saying is not that your code is bad with this assumption, but that there's an issue with the assumption itself.

Comment: Also, there's no point in the `:Status` part of the `status` declaration. Compiler will infer the type very well, and there's no much value in making the type explicit at this point.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Getting `null`/`undefined` on runtime, particularly when using TypeScript, is a sign of a much bigger problem. I'd solve _that_ problem instead of making workarounds and defeating the purpose of TS. Also, `Status` was to clarify that `status` is of `Status` because it's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: "sign of a much bigger problem" -- not necessarily, especially when front-end talks to an API we don't have control over. Nobody says that workaround is a good idea, but your assumption was too broad. If the API guarantees non-null values for the fields, the code is fine. The `Status` type would be better described by explicit type declaration, rather than `status: Status = ...` since, as I said it's inferred anyway.